# Can I use Plain PHP functions in tpl file?

Tags: theming, security

I have a `tpl.php` page for login form in my drupal site in which have 4 images.

I need to display only one of these 4 images randomly on each page load.

I can easily do this in less than 10 lines of code using the php `rand()` function.

But is it advisable to directly use such functions in tpl files.
Could this have some sort of security risk?

UPDATE:

The 4 images that I talked about. I have just uploaded them to `sites/default/files/images` folder and have included them in tpl file using following code:

```
<img src="http://mysite.com/sites/default/files/images/image.jpg"/>
```

I have a feeling that this is unsafe too. Please advise.

Comment: Security risk, not so much. But you will have problems with caching. Templates should be used for display only; all business logic should go elsewhere, namely in a template preprocess function

Comment: @Clive: Thanks. Also, Please see the updated question.

Comment: Your update falls under "not best practice", but why do you consider it to be unsafe? What attack vector do you feel you're introducing, or opening up?

Comment: I have read that when uploading a file file_save_upload may be used which gives the file a temporary status and these files are periodically cleaned. If I directly upload a file, could there be a similar issue?

Comment: No, Drupal only purges _managed_ files that have a temp status in the file_managed table. It won't touch anything you've uploaded manually

Comment: Also, a file uploaded from inside of drupal has URL like: `http://mysite.com/sites/default/files//styles/medium/public/image.gif?itok=_Hyz0SVE` but in my case my file has URL: `http://mysite.com/sites/default/files/images/image.jpg` which shows the complete directory structure

Comment: If someone has told you that showing the full path to an image located on a website is a security risk - stop listening to them :) Then get them to [read this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/237/how-can-i-obscure-the-fact-my-site-uses-drupal)

Comment: I'd rather display all the images in the template, then use javascript and css to do the random showing/hiding. You will get a page that can be cached by Drupal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of question:

You may output as form item the output of your custom function, where contain logic to get random image:

```
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'user_login') {
        $form['img_item'] = array(
          '#type' => 'markup',
          '#markup' => my_random_image_output(),
          '#weight' => -50
        );
    }
}

function my_random_image_output() {
    $output = '';

    // your custom logic to output one image $output = '<img src=".... />'

    return $output;
}
```