# Remove the X-generator header from the response

Tags: 8, security

I want to remove the CMS type and version disclosure , which Drupal is returning in the *X-Generator:Drupal 8 ([https://www.drupal.org)](https://www.drupal.org)_)* header.

I am using the following code, but it removes the x-generator header, but I can still see *X-Generator:Drupal 8 ([https://www.drupal.org)](https://www.drupal.org)_)* in the browser header response.

```
function xxx_page_attachments_alter(&$data, &$context1 = NULL, &$context2 = NULL) {
    foreach ($data['#attached']['html_head'] as $key => $attachment) {
        if ($attachment[1] == 'system_meta_generator') {
          unset($data['#attached']['html_head'][$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix my code?

Comment: You have to override the \Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\ResponseGeneratorSubscriber which is response_generator_subscriber service via ServiceProviderBase. Also check the \Drupal\Core\Mail\MailManager::doMail

Comment: Drupal is not giving any hint about the exact version, and they can know if you are using Drupal 8 or Drupal 7 in other ways. Removing that tag is doing what they call _securing by obscuring_ which is never a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest method is to remove the header in a custom EventSubscriber:

```
$response->headers->remove('X-Generator');
```

See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/201297/47547 for an example.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly the question you are asking, but...

I wrote a detailed answer to the idea of [How can I obscure what I am using to run my site?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/237/how-can-i-obscure-what-i-am-using-to-run-my-site/20608#20608) Adding it as an answer here in case it's useful to you as you consider working on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link, Created custom module to do that.

@https://github.com/vikrantrc/Remove-X-Generator

Answer (score 0):

@gaurav should also be working.  For me it seems to work

```
function THEMENAME_page_attachments_alter(&$data) {
  foreach ($data['#attached']['html_head'] as $key => $attachment) {
    if ($attachment[1] == 'system_meta_generator') {
      unset($data['#attached']['html_head'][$key]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to remove the `response_generator_subscriber` service responsible for adding `X-Generator` in the first place. It's all it does so nothing (other than Core's tests) should depend on it.

Simply drop in a `Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ServiceProviderInterface` implementation into your module like this:

`my_module/src/MyModuleServiceProvider.php:`

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\ws_main;

use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ServiceProviderBase;

/**
 * Remove the service adding the X-Generator header.
 */
class MyModuleServiceProvider extends ServiceProviderBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function alter(ContainerBuilder $container) {
    $container->removeDefinition('response_generator_subscriber');
  }

}
```

Important to note is that the class (and filename) must be a CamelCased version of your module's machine name (First character capitalized, remove any underscore and capitalize the next character) as noted in the [documentation on altering services](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/altering-existing-services-providing-dynamic-services). After clearing the cache - rebuilding the service registry - there should even be a tiny performance gain with this method, compared to adding and then removing the header on every response.

Answer (score 0):

**Without coding**

Remove X-Generator is a common requirement for Drupal sites. The [Mix](https://www.drupal.org/project/mix) module can deal with this and many other common situations without coding.

By checking the "Remove X-Generator" checkbox in `/admin/config/mix`, the following items can easily be removed:

- The meta tag `<meta name="Generator" content="Drupal 10 (https://www.drupal.org)">` from the page source code.
- The "X-Generator" in the HTTP header.

**Coding**

These only take a few lines of code.

To remove the `<meta name="Generator" content="Drupal 10 (https://www.drupal.org)">`, implement this in `[yourmodule].module` file.

@see https://git.drupalcode.org/project/mix/-/blob/1.x/mix.module#L96

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments_alter().
 */
function HOOK_page_attachments_alter(array &$attachments) {
  foreach ($attachments['#attached']['html_head'] as $key => $attachment) {
    if ($attachment[1] == 'system_meta_generator') {
      unset($attachments['#attached']['html_head'][$key]);
    }
  }
}
```

To remove the "X-Generator" HTTP header, you can implement an EventSubscriber.

@see https://git.drupalcode.org/project/mix/-/blob/1.x/src/EventSubscriber/MixSubscriber.php#L113

```
  public function onKernelResponse(ResponseEvent $event) {
    $response = $event->getResponse();
    $response->headers->remove('X-Generator');
  }
```